# Data File Input/Output Error

Tags: c++, arrays, file-io, struct, fstream

This program is to simulate a Bank's computer terminal.

The very first time I run the program and choose option 6 without first opening an account I get the correct display of: ***THERE ARE NO ACTIVE ACCOUNTS***

Then I rerun the program and select option 1 to open a new account and the necessary info. Then when I select option 6 it displays:

```
              Baton Rouge Trust Bank
                Customers Listing
 100 Les Miles Dr., Baton Rouge, Louisiana 70802
===========================================================
a/c #            First Name        Last Name        Balance  
-----------------------------------------------------------   
1234-56-78       Jane              Doe              500      
                                                    0
===========================================================
```

From there it gets worse with each time I run the program with zeros popping on in more places. For example:

```
              Baton Rouge Trust Bank
                Customers Listing
100 Les Miles Dr., Baton Rouge, Louisiana 70802
===========================================================
a/c #            First Name        Last Name        Balance  
-----------------------------------------------------------
                             0                0        
                             0                0        
1234-56-78       Jane              Doe              500      
                             0                0
                                              0
===========================================================
```

I can't figure out what's causing them, especially on the second program run through when there should only be one bank account.

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int MAX_CUSTOMERS = 1000;
const double OVER_DRAFT = 35.00;

struct AccountInfo
{
    string acNum;
    string fName;
    string lName;
    char midInitial;
    double balance;
};

int linearSearch(string acno, const AccountInfo customers[], int numAccs)
{
   int i;
   for (i=0; i<numAccs; i++)
   {
      if (customers[i].acNum == acno)
         return i;
   }
   return -1;
}

void openAccount(string acno, string fName, string lName, char midInit, double initBal,     AccountInfo customers[], int& numAccs)
{
   customers[numAccs].acNum = acno;
   customers[numAccs].lName = lName;
   customers[numAccs].fName = fName;
   customers[numAccs].midInitial = midInit;
   customers[numAccs].balance = initBal;
   numAccs++;
}

void closeAccount(string acno, AccountInfo customers[], int& numAccs)
{
  int row = linearSearch(acno,customers,numAccs);
  while (row < numAccs)
   {
     customers[row] = customers[row+1];
     row++;
 }
  numAccs--;
}

void deposit(string acno, double amount, AccountInfo customers[], int numAccs)
{
   int row = linearSearch(acno,customers,numAccs);
   customers[row].balance = customers[row].balance + amount;
}

void withdraw(string acno, double amount, AccountInfo customers[], int numAccs)
{
   int row = linearSearch(acno,customers,numAccs);
   if (amount <= customers[row].balance)
     customers[row].balance = customers[row].balance - amount;
   else if (amount > customers[row].balance)
     customers[row].balance = customers[row].balance - amount - OVER_DRAFT;
}

void inquiry(string acno, const AccountInfo customers[], int numAccs)
{
  int row = linearSearch(acno,customers,numAccs); 
  cout<<"----------------------------------"<<endl;
  cout<<"customer: "<<customers[row].fName<<" "<<customers[row].midInitial<<" "        <<customers[row].lName<<endl;
  cout<<"A/C #: "<<customers[row].acNum<<endl;
  cout<<"Balance: $"<<customers[row].balance<<endl;
  cout<<"----------------------------------"<<endl;
}

void customersList(const AccountInfo customers[], int numAccs)
{   
 cout<<right<<setw(40)<<"Baton Rouge Trust Bank"<<endl;
 cout<<right<<setw(37)<<"Customers Listing"<<endl;
 cout<<right<<setw(52)<<"100 Les Miles Dr., Baton Rouge, Louisiana 70802"<<endl;
 cout<<"==========================================================="<<endl;
 cout<<left<<setw(17)<<"a/c #"<<setw(18)<<"First Name"<<setw(17)<<"Last Name"<<setw(9)    <<"Balance"<<endl;
 cout<<"-----------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;

for (int index=0; index<=numAccs; index++)
{
    if (numAccs==0)
    {
        cout<<"***THERE ARE NO ACTIVE ACCOUNTS***"<<endl;
    }
    else 
    {
    cout<<left<<setw(17)<<customers[index].acNum<<setw(18)<<customers[index].fName<<setw(17)<<customers[index].lName<<setw(9)<<customers[index].balance<<endl;
    }
}
 cout<<"==========================================================="<<endl;
}

void menu()
{
    cout<<endl<<endl;
cout<<" Baton Rouge Trust ATM "<<endl;
cout<<"========================"<<endl;
cout<<"OPEN ACCOUNT..........[1]"<<endl;
cout<<"CLOSE AN ACCOUNT......[2]"<<endl;
cout<<"DEPOSIT...............[3]"<<endl;
cout<<"WITHDRAW..............[4]"<<endl;
cout<<"BALANCE INQUIRY.......[5]"<<endl;
cout<<"CUSTOMER LISTING......[6]"<<endl;
cout<<"EXIT..................[0]"<<endl;
}

int main()
{
   AccountInfo customers[MAX_CUSTOMERS];

   string acno, lName, fName;
   double initBal, amount;
   char midInit;

   int numAccs=0, pos, option;
   fstream acInfoIn, acInfoOut;

   acInfoIn.open("acinfo.dbf",ios::in);
   numAccs = 0;
   while (numAccs <MAX_CUSTOMERS && acInfoIn>>customers[numAccs].acNum)
    {
      acInfoIn>>customers[numAccs].lName>>customers[numAccs].fName
              >>customers[numAccs].midInitial>>customers[numAccs].balance;

      numAccs++;

    }
    acInfoIn.close();

   do
   {
      menu();
      cout<<endl;
      cout<<"Select an option->";
      cin>>option;
      cout<<endl;
      switch(option)
      {
         case 1:
                cout<<"Enter a 10-character long account number->";
                cin>>acno;
                if (acno.length() != 10)
                {
                   cout<<acno<<" must be 10-character long."<<endl;
                }
                else if (linearSearch(acno,customers,numAccs) > 0)
                {
                   cout<<acno<<" cannot be assigned to multiple customers."<<endl;
                }
            else
            {
               cout<<"Customer's first name ->";;
               cin>>fName;
               cout<<"Customer's middle initial ->";
               cin>>midInit;
               cout<<"Customer's last name ->";
cin>>lName;
               cout<<"Initial Deposit ->";
               cin>>initBal;
               if (initBal < 25.00)
                  cout<<"The initial balance required for a new account must be at least $25.00."<<endl;
               else
                  openAccount(acno,fName,lName,midInit,initBal,customers,numAccs);
            }
            break;
     case 2:
            cout<<"Enter a 10-character long account number->";
            cin>>acno;
            if (acno.length() != 10)
               cout<<acno<<" must be 10 characters long."<<endl;
            else if (linearSearch(acno,customers,numAccs) < 0)
               cout<<acno<<" is not a valid account number."<<endl;
            else
             {
              int pos = linearSearch(acno,customers,numAccs);
              if (customers[pos].balance != 0)
                 cout<<"This account still has money in its account;  thus it cannot be closed."<<endl;
              else
                 closeAccount(acno,customers,numAccs);
              }
             break;
     case 3:
            cout<<"Enter a 10-character long account number->";
            cin>>acno;
            if (acno.length() != 10)
            {
               cout<<acno<<" must be 10-character long."<<endl;
            }
            else if (linearSearch(acno,customers,numAccs) < 0)
               {
 cout<<acno<<" is not a valid account."<<endl;
                }
                else
                {
                   cout<<"Enter the amount to be deposited-> ";
               cin>>amount;
               if (amount <= 0)
                  cout<<"The amount to be deposited must be at least a penny."<<endl;
               else
                  deposit(acno,amount,customers,numAccs);      
            }         
            break;                  
     case 4: 
            cout<<"Enter a 10-charcter long account number->";  
            cin>>acno;
             if (acno.length() != 10)
               cout<<acno<<" must be 10 characters long."<<endl;
            else if (linearSearch(acno,customers,numAccs) < 0)
               cout<<acno<<" is not a valid account number."<<endl;
            else
            { 
              cout<<"Enter amount withdrawn->";              
              cin>>amount;                   
              if (amount <= 0) 
                 cout<<"This amount is invalid. The amount withdrawn must at least be a penny.";
              else 
                 withdraw(acno,amount,customers,numAccs);      
             }        
            break;                  
     case 5: 
            cout<<"Enter a 10-charcter long account number->"; 
            cin>>acno;
             if (acno.length() != 10)
                   cout<<acno<<" must be 10 characters long."<<endl;
else if (linearSearch(acno,customers,numAccs) < 0)
                   cout<<acno<<" is not a valid account number."<<endl;
                else
                 inquiry(acno,customers,numAccs);
                break;
     case 6:
            customersList(customers, numAccs);
            break;
     case 0:
            break;
     default:
            cout<<"Invalid menu option"<<endl;
  }
}while (option != 0);

   acInfoOut.open("acinfo.dbf",ios::out);
       for (pos=0; pos < MAX_CUSTOMERS; pos++)
        {
         acInfoOut<<customers[pos].acNum<<endl;
         acInfoOut<<customers[pos].lName<<endl;
         acInfoOut<<customers[pos].fName<<endl;
         acInfoOut<<customers[pos].midInitial<<endl;
         acInfoOut<<customers[pos].balance<<endl;       
        }
      acInfoOut.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this is way to much code. you definitivly should read [sscce](http://sscce.org/). also how do you try to figure out the problem? did you use a debuger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like this

```
acInfoOut.open("acinfo.dbf",ios::out);
for (pos=0; pos < MAX_CUSTOMERS; pos++)
{
    ...
}
acInfoOut.close();
```

I think you should do this

```
acInfoOut.open("acinfo.dbf",ios::out);
for (pos=0; pos < numAccs; pos++)
{
    ...
}
acInfoOut.close();
```

I.e. limit the output to the number of accounts you actually have.